What do you call an apartment building in which there are condominium units?
A condominium inside a property complex is a unit owned by an individual owner, rather than rented, as in case of apartments.
When we talk about the entire building, in case of apartments, we call it an "apartment complex" or a "apartment building". In British English they say "block of flats".
I was wondering, what should we call a this property complex (consisting of condominiums) if we want to emphasize that there are only condominiums there, not apartments.
A condo(minium) complex?
Looking at this link on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condominium there's a picture there, which seems to refer to the entire building as a condominium. So, a condominium is both the entire building and the individual unit?

So far as I can see, condominiums are just apartments that are owned rather than rented by whoever lives there. In British English they're just flats, regardless of who owns them. Obviously in some buildings, some flats are owner-occupied, while others house tenants. But no-one usually needs to distinguish buildings which are entirely owner-occupied from those entirely occupied by tenants. Or a mixture of both. Who cares? And how could you be sure anyway?

As we say in American English, "Who wants to know?"  In American English, when such a building is advertised as now accepting tenants, it is typically called ______ Condominiums. Not that it couldn't be called a "condo complex" but that term, though it is not pejorative, lacks "cachet". So you'd need to state your purpose for this name. How would it be used?  Are you giving someone directions?  You will see a large condo complex on the corner.   Are you drawing up an announcement for the real estate section of the newspaper?

Buildings with commercial tenants, condos, and rental apartments are common, and the casual terminology hasn't caught up with the complexities of such situations. There's no single word out there in general use that unambiguously means "condo-only building".

I own a condominium, and I call the entire set of buildings a "condominium complex", by analogy with apartment complex.
Condo complexes usually have a name, and the name is often in the form "XXX Condominiums". This is also similar to the way apartment complexes are named, it's frequently "XXX Apartments".
